# get current line through custom.js in jupyter

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I would like to insert text on the line where the cursor stands in a jupyter cell through custom.js . Is there something like a `Jupyter.notebook.get_current_line()` method? I would search the documentation but I can't find an overview of all the callable methods on `Jupyter.notebook`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jupyter uses CodeMirror for the text editor, so you'll have better luck looking in the CodeMirror API.

So, you can use `Jupyter.notebook.get_selected_cell().code_mirror` to get the current cell's CodeMirror instance.

Then you could use CodeMirror's [`getCursor`](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#getCursor) function to return the position of the cursor. It returns both the line number and how many characters into the line the cursor is (in the format {line: 0, ch: 0} for the first line first character)

Finally, you can use [`replaceRange`](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#replaceRange) to insert text. Simply save the current cursor position and use `replaceRange("Your text here",cursor,cursor)`

So, the final code would look something like

```
var cm = Jupyter.notebook.get_selected_cell().code_mirror;
var cursor = cm.getCursor();
cm.replaceRange("Your text here",cursor,cursor);
```